# What does the phrase '' in the form in which '' mean?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, word-meaning, phrase-usage

The definition ''in the form in which / in the form that'' was given by some native speakers about the phrase ''such as'' in following sentence.
Because as if the definition is technically defined in dictionary type, I can't take its meaning.
How should I understand the definition simple way?

''I shall give a short exposition of the essence of the genuine teaching of the
Buddha, such as we still find it in the Buddhist scriptures handed down to us in
the Pali language.''

Thanks a lot...

Comment: yes. now its definition is need to know. so I put this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You refer to native speakers, but do not give any exact quote. Nor do you explain what you find obscure in the unspecified explanations.

If the **only** definition you were given is that “such that” relates only to form, then that is not quite right. The sentence that you are asking about means

> I shall tell you concisely what is the meaning of the Buddha’s teaching as recorded in the Pali Canon.

“such that” does not concern itself with mere form. It expresses the idea that it is complete and accurate. Yes, the form is correct, but, more importantly the meaning is clear and intact.

Comment: Thank so much...

Comment: this's native's suggestions: 'It would make more sense with just as (meaning in the form in which), deleting the word such.

The text you’re quoting is an imperfect translation from German, first published in 1949.

As I said, all you need to do is delete “such” in that sentence in order to make it more idiomatic.

I shall give a short exposition of the essence of the genuine teaching of the Buddha, as we still find it in the Buddhist scriptures handed down to us in the Pali language. 

We can’t go into all the different uses of such and as, whether separately or together, here. ''